# Regex para dar match em título de citações

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou tentando capturar todos os títulos de citações em artigos científicos, minha regex está assim:

> (([A-ZÁÀÃÂÉÈÊÍÌÎÚÙÛÓÒÕÇ]{3,10}, ([A-Za-záàãâéèêíìîúùûóòõç-\ .].( ){0,1}){1,3})(et al.){0,1}([Oo]rg.){0,1}([Ee]d.){0,1}(; [A-ZÁÀÃÂÉÈÊÍÌÎÚÙÛÓÒÕÇ]{2,10}, ([A-Za-záàãâéèêíìîúùûóòõç-\ .].( ){0,1}){1,3}){0,2}){0,1}([A-ZÁÀÃÂÉÈÊÍÌÎÚÙÛÓÒÕÇ()\ .]{3,60}){0,1}([A-Za-z0-9:-áàãâéèêíìîúùûóòõç, ]{10,}.( ){0,1})(([A-Za-záàãâéèêíìîúùûóòõç-:\ /]){1,30}(, )\d{4}.){0,1}

Alguns exemplos de citações, com o título em negrito:

DI MAIO, P. **The Missing Pragmatic Link in the Semantic Web**. Business Intelligence Advisory Service Executive Update. v. 8, n. 7, 2008.

ECO, U. **Lector in Fabula: la cooperación interpretativa en el texto narrativo.** Barcelona: Lumen, 1987

ECO, U. **O conceito de texto.** São Paulo: T. A. Q. /EDUSP, 1984.

ECO, U. **Obra aberta: forma e indeterminação nas poéticas contemporâneas.** São Paulo: Perspectiva, 1988.

ECO, U. **Os limites da interpretação.** São Paulo: Pioneira, 2000.

EDMONDS, B. **The Pragmatic Roots of Context**. In: PROC. OF THE 2ND INTERNATIONAL AND INTERDISCIPLINARY CONFERENCE ON MODELING AND USING CONTEXT. Berlin; Heidelberg; New York, v. 1688, 1999.  Anais… v. 1688, p. 119-132, 1999.

BERNERS-LEE, T. **Semantic Web Concepts.** 2005a. Disponível em: http://www.w3.org/2005/Talks/0517-boit-tbl. Acesso em: 25 set. 2014

BERNERS-LEE, T. **Web for real people**. 2005b. Disponível em . Acesso em: 25 set. 2014.

BERNERS-LEE, T.; CAILLIAU, R. **WorldWideWeb: Proposal for a HyperText Project.** 1990. Disponível em: < http://www.w3.org/Proposal.html >. Acesso em: 13 out. 2014.

BERNERS-LEE, T.; HENDLER, J.; LASSILA, O. **The semantic web: a new form of web content that is meaningful to computers will unleash a revolution of new possibilities.** New York: Scientific American, 2001. Disponível em: http://www.sciam.com/2001/050lissue/0501berners-lee.html. Acesso em: 13 out. 2014.

BLAIR, D. C. **Information Retrieval and the Philosophy of Language.** Annual Review of Information Science and Tecchnology, v. 37, pp. 3-50, Medford, 2003.

BLAIR, D. C. **Wittgenstein, Language and Information: Back to the Rough Ground!** Dordrecht: Springer, 2006.

BONFIM, M. E. **Recuperação de Documentos Texto Usando Um Modelo Probabilístico Estendido.** Piracicaba: UNIMEP, 2006. 131 f.  Dissertação (Mestrado em Ciência da Computação).  Mestrado em Ciência da Computação. Universidade Metodista de Piracicaba, 2006.

BORLUND, P. **The Concept of Relevance in IR.** Journal of the American Society for Information Science and Technology, v.54, p. 913-925, 2003.

BORST, W. N. **Construction of engineering ontologies.** Tese (Doutorado em Information and Knowledge Systems). University of Tweenty – Centre for Telematica and Information Technology, Enschede, Nederland, 1997.

BOUNDLESS. **Boundless Psychology.** 201X. Disponível em < https://www.boundless.com/psychology/textbooks/boundless-psychology-textbook/ > Acesso em: 13 ago. 2014.

BRATT, S. **Semantic Web, and Other Technologies to Watch.** 2008. Disponível em < http://www.w3.org/2008/Talks/1009-bratt-W3CSemTech/Overview.html > Acesso em: 13 ago. 2014.

BRÉAL, M. **Semantics: studies in the science of meaning.** New York: Henry Holt & Company, 1900.

BRICKLEY, D.; MILLER, L. **FOAF Vocabulary Specification 0.9.** 2007. Disponível em < http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/20070524.html > Acesso em: 17 maio 2015.

BRITISH LIBRARY. **Sample Data.** Disponível em . Acesso em: 12 dez. 2014.

BRUYNE, P. de, HERMAN, J., SCHOUTHEETE, M. de. **Dinâmica da pesquisa em ciências sociais.** Rio de Janeiro: Francisco Alves, 1977.

BUFREM, L. S, et al. **Modelizando práticas para a socialização de informações- a construção de saberes no ensino superior.** Perspectivas em Ciência da Informação, Belo Horizonte, v.15, n.2, p.22-41, maio/ago. 2010.

**ESTES NÃO SÃO TODOS OS CASOS, A LISTA COMPLETA DAS CITAÇÕES SE ENCONTRA AQUI:**

Para teste: https://regex101.com/r/n2554R/1/

Comment: Esse foi o melhor que eu consegui: [demo Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/n2554R/2) e [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/7Roon713B8-KhI3z). Mas como já te disseram no SOen: _this is a natural language problem that can't be solved with a regex._

Comment: use [A-zÀ-ú] ou até [A-zÀ-ÿ] para capturar letras acentuadas, não faça isso => [A-ZÁÀÃÂÉÈÊÍÌÎÚÙÛÓÒÕÇ]

Comment: @danieltakeshi O que é um "natural language problem"? Pq isso não pode ser resolvido com regex? Estou começando a usar regex faz pouco tempo.

Comment: Pois é muito complexo para um Regex. A [Linguagem Natural](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processamento_de_linguagem_natural) é muito mais complexa, pois precisa da compreensão de línguas humanas naturais. Vendo na lista de demo do Regex101 você perceberá vários modos de citar sem possuir um padrão. O que é Possível com Regex, é a procura de citações dentro de algum padrão/norma com regras claras. Por exemplo ABNT ou IEEE. Mas para todos os tipos de citações é necessário algo como Inteligência Artificial.

Comment: Um site que sugiro para resolver este problema é o [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions), mas antes de criar uma competição, você precisa estudar sobre a Data Science e entender melhor como funcionam as competições deste site. Em que há várias competições que valem dinheiro para quem resolvê-las. **Obs.: No LaTeX você consegue estes campos mais facilmente, porém o artigo deverá estar feito em LaTeX.**

Comment: @danieltakeshi Obrigado pelo esclarecimento!

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 2):

Em vez de usar regex, sugiro quebrar em array por `. e espaço` e pegar o segundo índice `[1]` que será justamente o Título. Veja:

```js
var strings = [
   "DI MAIO, P. The Missing Pragmatic Link in the Semantic Web. Business Intelligence Advisory Service Executive Update. v. 8, n. 7, 2008.",
   "ECO, U. Lector in Fabula: la cooperación interpretativa en el texto narrativo. Barcelona: Lumen, 1987",
   "ECO, U. O conceito de texto. São Paulo: T. A. Q. /EDUSP, 1984.",

   "ECO, U. Obra aberta: forma e indeterminação nas poéticas contemporâneas. São Paulo: Perspectiva, 1988.",
   "ECO, U. Os limites da interpretação. São Paulo: Pioneira, 2000.",
   "EDMONDS, B. The Pragmatic Roots of Context. In: PROC. OF THE 2ND INTERNATIONAL AND INTERDISCIPLINARY CONFERENCE ON MODELING AND USING CONTEXT. Berlin; Heidelberg; New York, v. 1688, 1999. Anais… v. 1688, p. 119-132, 1999.",
   "BERNERS-LEE, T. Semantic Web Concepts. 2005a. Disponível em: http://www.w3.org/2005/Talks/0517-boit-tbl. Acesso em: 25 set. 2014",
   "BERNERS-LEE, T. Web for real people. 2005b. Disponível em . Acesso em: 25 set. 2014.",
   "BERNERS-LEE, T.; CAILLIAU, R. WorldWideWeb: Proposal for a HyperText Project. 1990. Disponível em: < http://www.w3.org/Proposal.html >. Acesso em: 13 out. 2014.",
   "BERNERS-LEE, T.; HENDLER, J.; LASSILA, O. The semantic web: a new form of web content that is meaningful to computers will unleash a revolution of new possibilities. New York: Scientific American, 2001. Disponível em: http://www.sciam.com/2001/050lissue/0501berners-lee.html. Acesso em: 13 out. 2014."
]

for(var x=0; x<strings.length; x++){
   var titulo = strings[x].split(". ")[1];
   document.querySelector("#res").innerHTML += strings[x].replace(titulo,"<span style='color:blue;'>"+titulo+"</span>")+"<br><b style='color: red;'>Título -></b> <b>"+titulo+"</b><br><br>";
}
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>
```

> Considerando que no meio do título não haja `. e espaço`.

**O código seria este:**

```js
var string = "DI MAIO, P. The Missing Pragmatic Link in the Semantic Web. Business Intelligence Advisory Service Executive Update. v. 8, n. 7, 2008";

var titulo = string.split(". ")[1];
console.log(titulo);
```

---

Uma outra forma seria manipulando strings:

```js
var strings = [
   "DI MAIO, P. The Missing Pragmatic Link in the Semantic Web. Business Intelligence Advisory Service Executive Update. v. 8, n. 7, 2008.",
   "ECO, U. Lector in Fabula: la cooperación interpretativa en el texto narrativo. Barcelona: Lumen, 1987",
   "ECO, U. O conceito de texto. São Paulo: T. A. Q. /EDUSP, 1984.",
   "ECO, U. Obra aberta: forma e indeterminação nas poéticas contemporâneas. São Paulo: Perspectiva, 1988.",
   "ECO, U. Os limites da interpretação. São Paulo: Pioneira, 2000.",
   "EDMONDS, B. The Pragmatic Roots of Context. In: PROC. OF THE 2ND INTERNATIONAL AND INTERDISCIPLINARY CONFERENCE ON MODELING AND USING CONTEXT. Berlin; Heidelberg; New York, v. 1688, 1999. Anais… v. 1688, p. 119-132, 1999.",
   "BERNERS-LEE, T. Semantic Web Concepts. 2005a. Disponível em: http://www.w3.org/2005/Talks/0517-boit-tbl. Acesso em: 25 set. 2014",
   "BERNERS-LEE, T. Web for real people. 2005b. Disponível em . Acesso em: 25 set. 2014.",
   "BERNERS-LEE, T.; CAILLIAU, R. WorldWideWeb: Proposal for a HyperText Project. 1990. Disponível em: < http://www.w3.org/Proposal.html >. Acesso em: 13 out. 2014.",
   "BERNERS-LEE, T.; HENDLER, J.; LASSILA, O. The semantic web: a new form of web content that is meaningful to computers will unleash a revolution of new possibilities. New York: Scientific American, 2001. Disponível em: http://www.sciam.com/2001/050lissue/0501berners-lee.html. Acesso em: 13 out. 2014."
]

for(var x=0; x<strings.length; x++){

   for(var y=0; y<strings[x].length; y++){

      var letra = strings[x][y];
      
      if(letra.match(/[a-z]/)){
         var titIni = y-(strings[x][y-1] == " " ? 2 : 1);
         break;
      }
   }

var titulo = strings[x].substring(titIni,strings[x].indexOf(". ", titIni));
document.querySelector("#res").innerHTML += strings[x].replace(titulo,"<span style='color:blue;'>"+titulo+"</span>")+"<br><b style='color: red;'>Título -></b> <b>"+titulo+"</b><br><br>";

}
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>
```

> Considerando também que no meio do título não haja . e espaço.

**Código:**

```js
var string = "ECO, U. O conceito de texto. São Paulo: T. A. Q. /EDUSP, 1984.";

   for(var x=0; x<string.length; x++){

      var letra = string[x];
      
      if(letra.match(/[a-z]/)){
         var titIni = x-(string[x-1] == " " ? 2 : 1);
         break;
      }
   }

var titulo = string.substring(titIni,string.indexOf(". ", titIni));
console.log(titulo);
```

Answer (score 1):

A logica que pensei foi a seguinte :

- Autores
- Titulo
- Descrições

Assim é possível definis as seguintes regras :

> **Autores** : sobrenome + virgula + espaço + nome + ponto = `BERNERS-LEE, T.`; Vários autores são separados por `;` o ultimo autor termina com ponto `.` sempre.
>
> **Titulo** : qualquer coisa que não tenha `;`,`.` no meio, mas deve terminar com `.`
>
> **Descrição** : qualquer coisa que vier depois do titulo.

#### REGEX

```
^((?:.+?, .+?;)*?(?:[^;\s]+?, .+?)\.)([^;]+?\.).*$
```

#### Explicação

- `(?:.+?, .+?;)*?(?:[^;\s]+?, .+?)\.)` - pega os autores

  - `(?:.+?, .+?;)*?` - cuida dos multi autores que sempre terminal com `;`
  - `(?:[^;\s]+?, .+?)\.)` - pega o ultimo autor, que nunca vai ter `;` e termina em `.`
- `([^;]+?\.)` - Pega o Titulo que termina com `.`
- `.*$` - Descrição, vai ate o final.

Veja em [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3xDVTw/1)

Comment: Não consegui entender o "?:" o que significa na regex?

Comment: @BrunoBrito quando você usa parenteses você cria um grupo, ao usar `(?: ...)` você basicamente diz que esse parenteses não vai gerar grupo.

Comment: Guilherme tua lógica funcionou perfeitamente, o problema é que mandei apenas uma porção do total de citações e essa solução não engloba todos os casos. Peguei algumas ideias da tua regex e adaptei para a minha, mas só não consegui achar uma forma de de dar match apenas no título, preciso achar uma forma de "parar" o match assim que o primeiro ponto final for encontrado. Link: https://regex101.com/r/PlkNWz/1
Você sabe como posso resolver isso?

Comment: @BrunoBrito esse tipo de coisa deveria ser posto na pergunta original, pois olhando para esse novo, da pra notar que quebra a minha logica assim como a do @dvd, pois tem alguns que o ultimo autor termina com `;`. aundo tiver mais tempo analiso o que pode ser feito

Comment: Certo, sua resposta está correta pois está de acordo com a pergunta, mas vou editar e colocar todos os casos da regex, erro meu.